# to-infinitive as a direct object(noun phrase)? (as in 'I promised to buy her a pizza tomorrow')

Tags: grammar, infinitives

I think this 'to' is some kind of connecting word. I think it connects a verb and what the verb intends. I think in this usage, the originally transitive verb becomes an intransitive verb needing a complement. I think some Americans could consider the to-infinitive as a adverbial complement that describe what the before verb intends, and 'to' as a connecting word. Do Americans or some Americans not regard it as a noun phrase, but as what I think of?

Comment: No, ***to*** there isn't a "connecting word". It's an ***infinitive marker***, same as *I **need to** buy a pizza*.

Comment: Also called a ***complementizer***. Part of the _for...to_ Infinitive Complementizer, as in _For him to leave now would be a mistake_ or _They asked for him to leave immediately_. Complementizers introduce subordinate clauses, and infinitives are subordinate clauses.  They are also often deleted when they're not necessary, but they can be put back in by listeners.